# How to create stream which handles both input and output in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream, c++-faq, streambuf

I'm trying to make a class that will be both input and output stream (like `std::cout` and `std::cin` ). I tried to overload operator `<<` and `>>`, but then, I understood that writing such code is not wise to do (as this would be an approach to rewrite C++ streams) and maintaining is very hard when classes like `std::basic_iostream`, `std::basic_ostream`, `std::basic_istream` are available in C++ standard library because I have to overload operators for each type. So, I tried to define my class like this:

```cpp
#include <istream>

class MyStream : public std::basic_iostream<char> {
public:
    MyStream() : std::basic_iostream<char>(stream_buffer) {}
};
```

My problem is with the first argument at constructor of `std::basic_iostream<char>` . As of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream/basic_iostream), `std::basic_iostream::basic_iostream` takes a pointer to a stream buffer derived from `std::basic_streambuf` :

```cpp
explicit basic_iostream( std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>* sb );
```

I have read and tried examples from [Apache C++ Standard Library User's Guide's chapter 38](https://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/38.html). It says that I have to pass a pointer to the stream buffer and there are three ways to do so:

- Create stream buffer before class initialization
- Take the stream buffer from another stream (using `rdbuf()` or similar member)
- Define a `basic_streambuf` object as a protected or private member

The last option fits best for my purpose, but if I directly create an object from the `std::basic_streambuf` class, it will do nothing, will it? So I defined another class which is derived from `std::basic_streambuf<char>`. But this time I can't understand what functions to define, because I don't know which function is called when data is inserted, extracted, and flushed.

**How can one create a stream with custom functionalities?**

---

**<sub>Note that this is an attempt to build a standard guide on creating C++ streams and stream buffers.</sub>**

Comment: You have the right idea. basic_streambuf does nothing, so you need to derive a class from basic_streambuf that does what you need. But this is far to big a topic to be answered here. There's a good [book](http://www.cppstdlib.com/) that covers this topic. Or you could take your chances and google.

Comment: @john I don't think asking how to implement a streambuf is too large to answer here. It's too large for *me* to answer here *right now*, but it could fit in the answer format.

Comment: Here is an example on how to use an LCD as an std::ostream: https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/devices/hwd/dev_HD44780_basic.h. The best manual about how to implement iostream is the standard (the problem is that the standard is not an easy lecture)

Comment: A more complicated example is to use UART as std::iostream: https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/microcontrollers/avr/avr_UART_iostream.h. Sorry, part of the coments are in spanish, but the reference to the standard all are in english.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Creating a class that behaves like a stream is easy. Let's say we want to create such class with the name `MyStream` , the definition of the class will be as simple as:

```cpp
#include <istream> // class "basic_iostream" is defined here

class MyStream : public std::basic_iostream<char> {
private:
    std::basic_streambuf buffer; // your streambuf object
public:
    MyStream() : std::basic_iostream<char>(&buffer) {} // note that ampersand
};
```

The constructor of your class should call the constructor of `std::basic_iostream<char>` with a **pointer** to a custom `std::basic_streambuf<char>` object. `std::basic_streambuf` is just a template class which defines the structure of a stream buffer. So you have to get your own stream buffer. You can get it in two ways:

1. **From another stream:** Every stream has a member `rdbuf` which takes no arguments and returns a pointer to the stream buffer being used by it. Example:

```cpp
...
std::basic_streambuf* buffer = std::cout.rdbuf(); // take from std::cout
...
```

2. **Create your own:** You can always create a buffer class by deriving from `std::basic_streambuf<char>` and customize it as you want.

Now we defined and implemented `MyStream` class, we need the stream buffer. Let's select option 2 from above and create our own stream buffer and name this `MyBuffer` . We will need the following:

1. **Constructor** to initialize the object.
2. **Continuous memory block to store output** by program temporarily.
3. **Continuous memory block to store input** from the user (or something other) temporarily.
4. **Method `overflow`** , which is called when allocated memory for storing output is full.
5. **Method `underflow`** , which is called when all input is read by the program and more input requested.
6. **Method `sync`** , which is called when output is flushed.

As we know what things are needed to create a stream buffer class, let's declare it:

```cpp
class MyBuffer : public std::basic_streambuf<char> {
private:
    char inbuf[10];
    char outbuf[10];

    int sync();
    int_type overflow(int_type ch);
    int_type underflow();
public:
    MyBuffer();
};
```

Here `inbuf` and `outbuf` are two arrays which will store input and output respectively. `int_type` is a special type which is like char and created to support multiple character types like `char` , `wchar_t` , etc.

Before we jump into the implementation of our buffer class, we need to know how the buffer will work.

To understand how buffers work, we need to know how arrays work. Arrays are nothing special but pointers to continuous memory. When we declare a `char` array with two elements, the operating system allocate `2 * sizeof(char)` memory for our program. When we access an element from the array with `array[n]` , it is converted to `*(array + n)` , where `n` is index number. When you add `n` to an array, it jumps to next `n * sizeof(<the_type_the_array_points_to>)` (figure 1). If you don't know what pointer arithmetics I would recommend you to learn that before you continue. [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) has a [good article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) on pointers for beginners.

```
             array    array + 1
               \        /
------------------------------------------
  |     |     | 'a' | 'b' |     |     |
------------------------------------------
    ...   105   106   107   108   ...
                 |     |
                 -------
                    |
            memory allocated by the operating system

                     figure 1: memory address of an array
```

As we know much about pointers now, let's see how stream buffers work. Our buffer contains two arrays `inbuf` and `outbuf` . But how the standard library would know input must be stored to `inbuf` and output must be stored to `outbuf` ? So, there two areas called get area and put area which is input and output area respectively.

Put area is specified with the following three pointers (figure 2):

- **`pbase()`** or **put base**: start of put area
- **`epptr()`** or **end put pointer**: end of put area
- **`pptr()`** or **put pointer**: where next character will be put

These are actually functions which return the corresponding pointer. These pointers are set by `setp(pbase, epptr)` . After this function call, `pptr()` is set to `pbase()` . To change it we'll use `pbump(n)` which repositions `pptr()` by n character, n can be positive or negative. Note that the stream will write to the previous memory block of `epptr()` but not `epptr()` .

```
  pbase()                         pptr()                       epptr()
     |                              |                             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o'  |     |     |     |     |     |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                                                      |
     --------------------------------------------------------
                                 |
                   allocated memory for the buffer

           figure 2: output buffer (put area) with sample data
```

Get area is specified with the following three pointers (figure 3):

- **`eback()`** or **end back**, start of get area
- **`egptr()`** or **end get pointer**, end of get area
- **`gptr()`** or **get pointer**, the position which is going to be read

These pointers are set with `setg(eback, gptr, egptr)` function. Note that the stream will read the previous memory block of `egptr()` but not `egptr()`.

```
  eback()                         gptr()                       egptr()
     |                              |                             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o'  | ' ' | 'C' | '+' | '+' |     |     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                                                      |
     --------------------------------------------------------
                                 |
                   allocated memory for the buffer

           figure 3: input buffer (get area) with sample data
```

Now that we have discussed almost all we need to know before creating a custom stream buffer, it's time to implement it! We'll try to implement our stream buffer such way that it will work like `std::cout` !

Let's start with the constructor:

```cpp
MyBuffer() {
    setg(inbuf+4, inbuf+4, inbuf+4);
    setp(outbuf, outbuf+9);
}
```

Here we set all three get pointers to one position, which means there are no readable characters, forcing `underflow()` when input wanted. Then we set put pointer in such a way so the stream can write to whole `outbuf` array except the last element. We'll preserve it for future use.

Now, let's implement `sync()` method, which is called when output is flushed:

```cpp
int sync() {
    int return_code = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (pptr() - pbase()); i++) {
        if (std::putchar(outbuf[i]) == EOF) {
            return_code = EOF;
            break;
        }
    }

    pbump(pbase() - pptr());
    return return_code;
}
```

This does it's work very easily. First, it determines how many characters there are to print, then prints one by one and repositions `pptr()` (put pointer). It returns EOF or -1 if character any character is EOF, 0 otherwise.

But what to do if put area is full? So, we need `overflow()` method. Let's implement it:

```cpp
int_type overflow(int_type ch) {
    *pptr() = ch;
    pbump(1);

    return (sync() == EOF ? EOF : ch);
}
```

Not very special, this just put the extra character into the preserved last element of `outbuf` and repositions `pptr()` (put pointer), then calls `sync()` . It returns EOF if `sync()` returned EOF, otherwise the extra character.

Everything is now complete, except input handling. Let's implement `underflow()` , which is called when all characters in input buffer are read:

```cpp
int_type underflow() {
    int keep = std::max(long(4), (gptr() - eback()));
    std::memmove(inbuf + 4 - keep, gptr() - keep, keep);

    int ch, position = 4;
    while ((ch = std::getchar()) != EOF && position <= 10) {
        inbuf[position++] = char(ch);
        read++;
    }
    
    if (read == 0) return EOF;
    setg(inbuf - keep + 4, inbuf + 4 , inbuf + position);
    return *gptr();
}
```

A little difficult to understand. Let's see what's going on here. First, it calculates how many characters it should preserve in buffer (which is at most 4) and stores it in the `keep` variable. Then it copies last `keep` number characters to the start of the buffer. This is done because characters can be put back into the buffer with `unget()` method of `std::basic_iostream` . Program can even read next characters without extracting it with `peek()` method of `std::basic_iostream` . After the last few characters are put back, it reads new characters until it reaches the end of the input buffer or gets EOF as input. Then it returns EOF if no characters are read, continues otherwise. Then it repositions all get pointers and return the first character read.

As our stream buffer is implemented now, we can setup our stream class `MyStream` so it uses our stream buffer. So we change the private `buffer` variable:

```cpp
...
private:
    MyBuffer buffer;
public:
...
```

You can now test your own stream, it should take input from and show output from terminal.

---

Note that **this stream and buffer can only handle `char` based input and output**. Your class must derive from corresponding class to handle other types of input and output (e.g `std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t>` for wide characters) and implement member functions or method to so they can handle that type of character.

Comment: Amazing explanation. One small recommendation though, your get input example would be better if readable characters were all to the right of pointer rather than left.